# Specific text in label disturbing the alignment

Tags: html, css, user-interface, alignment

I have a login page which takes a username and password.
I am facing a very strange problem.
When i put "Username" as label text in first label the text comes above the input but when i put "Password" as text for first label it comes normally that is side by side.

[image: "Username" as text]
[image: "password" as text]

Code for "Password" as text

```
 <div class="main" style="width: 25%;margin-left: 500px;" align="center">
                     <div style = "background-color:blue; color:#FFFFFF; padding:3px; "><b>Login</b></div>

                <div style = "margin:30px; color: black" class='inv'>

                   <form action = "" method = "post">
                   <br/>
                      <label>Password  :</label><input type = "text" id="username" name = "username" class = "box" value=""  required/><br /><br />
                      <label>Password  :</label><input type = "password" name = "password" id="password" class = "box" value=""  required /><br/><br />
                      <input type = "submit" value = " Submit " class=".btn-primary" /><br />
                   </form>

                   <div style = "font-size:11px; color:#cc0000; margin-top:10px"><?php error_reporting(0);echo $error; ?></div>

                </div>

             </div>
    </div>
```

Code for "username" as text

```
<div class="main" style="width: 25%;margin-left: 500px;" align="center">
                     <div style = "background-color:blue; color:#FFFFFF; padding:3px; "><b>Login</b></div>

                <div style = "margin:30px; color: black" class='inv'>

                   <form action = "" method = "post">
                   <br/>
                      <label>username:  :</label><input type = "text" id="username" name = "username" class = "box" value=""  required/><br /><br />
                      <label>Password  :</label><input type = "password" name = "password" id="password" class = "box" value=""  required /><br/><br />
                      <input type = "submit" value = " Submit " class=".btn-primary" /><br />
                   </form>

                   <div style = "font-size:11px; color:#cc0000; margin-top:10px"><?php error_reporting(0);echo $error; ?></div>

                </div>

             </div>
```

Please help!!

Comment: Even though the number of characters in 'Username' and 'Password' are same the actual width of both are different. 'Username' is slightly wider than 'Password'. You are trying to fit this by using hard coded width and alignment which doesn't work in other screens anyway. Immediate fix/workaround is the increase the width of parent div to 26% or decrease the margin from 30px to 25px. But this will still not look good and may not work in other window sizes.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Like @Nawed Khan said, the source of your problem stems from your hard-coded styles.
This line in particular causes the width to scale with the viewport (size of the browser window), and the margin-left pushes the `div` to the side by 500px, thus it won't be centered on a different browser or when the browser is resized.

`<div class="main" style="width: 25%;margin-left: 500px;" align="center">`

The short fix is to increase the width.

`<div class="main" style="width: 500px;margin: 0 auto;" align="center">`

Giving it a hard value can work for now.

But that introduces it's own sets of scaling caveat for different screens, so if you're serious about making it work for different screens, consider looking into responsive design.

Comment: I changed the 25% to 30% it is working for now.But i didn't understand how "username" and "password" have different width.Can anyone of you plz clarify that.Thanx for the answer

Comment: Text with the same character count may have different width because each character itself may have a different width. I say "may" because it actually depends on the font itself (for example: georgia font will have different width while consolas will not).

Here's a [demonstration](https://codepen.io/adam_ho/pen/xyzOYg).

P.s.: There is a html DOM property for the width of an element called "offsetWidth" which can be found in the javascript of the demo.

Answer (score 0):

Please reduced the size of input filed, maybe that will help.